# Leer XML en Visual .NET

Tags: .net, xml, visual

Hola tengo un XML asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿como lo debo hacer para leer solo los valores destacados en amarillo en Visual .NET 2012?, seria el folio, el rut del emisor y el neto

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar xPath:

```
using System.Xml;

 var doc = XDocument.Load("myconfig.xml")
 var result1 = doc.XPathSelectElement("encabezado/idDoc/folio");
 Console.WriteLine(result1.OuterXml);
 var result2 = doc.XPathSelectElement("encabezado/emisor/RTUemisor");
 Console.WriteLine(result2.OuterXml);
 var result3= doc.XPathSelectElement("encabezado/totales/MNtneto");
 Console.WriteLine(result3.OuterXml);
```